# how to store object which contains object

Tags: c#, db4o

I have a small problem
How to store object which contains another object?
for example

Object Person

Person
{
Name,
Mother
}

where Mother is another Object of the same class Person

thx for help
lczernik

Comment: Have you considered storing them in a `<List>`?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public Person Mother;
    Person (string name, Person mother)
    {
        Name = name;
        Mother = mother;
    }
}
```

use it like

```
Person me = new Person("user2069747", new Person("user2069747's mom name", null));
// null was used because you may not know the name of your grand mom;
Console.WriteLine(me.Name) // prints your name
Console.WriteLine(me.Mother.Name) // prints your mom's name
```

Answer (score 0):

db4o will store the whole object graph automatically for you however, due to performance optimizations, you need to pay attention to the following scenarios:

- Object retrieval
- Object updates

In both cases db4o will perform the operation requested to certain depths, set through the following configuration parameters:

- [Activation depth](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-7.12/net35/reference/Content/configuration/common/activation_depth.htm)
- [Update depth](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-7.12/net35/reference/Content/configuration/common/update_depth.htm)

So given the following model you can store the object graph in a single call:

```
using System;
using Db4objects.Db4o;

namespace Db4oSample
{
    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Person Mother { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name + (Mother != null ? "(" + Mother + ")" : "");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var grandMother = new Person {Name = "grandma"};
            var mother = new Person {Name = "mother", Mother = grandMother };
            var son = new Person {Name = "son", Mother = mother};

            using(var db = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile("database.odb")) // Closes the db after storing the object graph
            {
                db.Store(son);
            }

            using(var db = Db4oEmbedded.OpenFile("database.odb"))
            {
                var result = db.Query<Person>(p => p.Name == "son");
                if (result.Count != 1)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Expected 1 Person, got " + result.Count);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps